# Need mini-form to append tracking number to URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm needing to create a little form to append a tracking number to the end of a URL, and then post the new URL below the form.

Here is an example resulting URL:
http://www.rlcarriers.com/shiptrace2.asp?traceseek=PRO&tracenum=091339083

The tracking number here is 091339083, so I need to be able to enter a different tracking number into this form to create a new URL that I can then click.

http://www.rlcarriers.com/shiptrace2.asp?traceseek=PRO&tracenum=(new tracking number)

Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://rlcarriers.com/shiptrace2.asp" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="traceseek" value="PRO" />
    <input type="text" name="tracenum" value="091339083" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```